# How to get rid of print from fabric clothing?

Tags: clothing

I have a shirt with a lot of print. The print is rather embarrassing to wear, but the shirt is beautiful.

I just want to get rid of the print I don't like. The printing has been done at a local shop, and when I scratched it, the paint came off with a little effort... I want to get rid of it faster, though, as I don't have time to scratch every single letter off, one by one.

Thanks in advance,

Abhigyan

EDIT:

[image: my shirt... Please don't follow link]

Comment: A picture of the shirt could be helpful. There are many different processes for adding print to a shirt, and each might require a different solution.

Comment: My shirt was printed at a shop, and upon scratching the print, it peels away. But I'll upload pictures Right away

Comment: If you have very cheap custom-printed T-shirts the logo washes off anyway after a few times in the washing machine. The edges peel up and you can brush it off with a wire brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can get a brush as shown from your house. Rub with this brush and remove the letters in bulk instead of going for scratching.

[image: fabric washing brush]

Afterward, you may have to clean the brush for leftovers, that you could do using ordinary water.

Comment: You may also be able to remove leftovers from the brush by running a hair comb through the brush's bristles.

Comment: @BrettFromLa Thanks friend, I think it does not require much attention as dust on a brush is just an ordinary situation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of scratching each one of them, you could press strong adhesive tape down on top of letters, and then peel the tape off and that will pull off the letter. I like using duct tape for nearly everything, so that may work. Try it with one letter first. Also, the tape may leave some adhesive on the shirt, so you might need to Google how to remove duct tape adhesive from fabric. (Or you could use a different kind of adhesive tape.)

Comment: Sticky tape glue does not stick well when wet, so after removing as much of the text you can, soak the fabric in water (a few minutes will be enough) and wash as usual.